# Como colar com indentação correta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ipython-notebook, indentação

Sempre dá muito trabalho para corrigir indentação após copiar e colar, mas tem um jeito de colar com indentação correta?
Por exemplo:

```
x = int(input("0 ou 1? "))
if x == 1:
    print("ON")                                                     
if x == 0:
    print("OFF")
```

Depois eu mudei da ideia, coloquei while loop por exemplo, eu copiei tudo e colei

Antes:

```
while True:
```

Depois de colar:

```
while True:
    x = int(input("0 ou 1? "))
if x == 1:
    print("ON")                                                     
if x == 0:
    print("OFF")
```

Tudo está errado. Deve ser assim:

```
while True:
    x = int(input("0 ou 1? "))
    if x == 1:
        print("ON")                                                     
    if x == 0:
        print("OFF")
```

Google Colaboratory tem esse recurso para colar com indentação? E Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Em vários IDEs, basta marcar o bloco depois de colá-lo e pressionar TAB

Comment: Isso vai depender inteiramente da ferramenta que você usa pra escrever o código (IDE, editor de texto, ...).